# "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $" in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to send a signup form to the server with retrofit. first I have this error:

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $.

I'm trying to fix it with add *Gson* to *Retrofit.Builder* like this:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

now, I have this error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

my server response is like this:

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Successful"
}
```

how to fix it?

> Update

my interface Api:

```
public interface SignUpApi {

@Multipart
@POST("signup_profile")
Call<SignUpResponseModel> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                     @Part("sample_disc") RequestBody imageFile,
                                     @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                     @Part("phone") RequestBody phone,
                                     @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                                     @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                                     @Part("username") RequestBody username);

}
```

send info code and get response:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
        RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etName.getText().toString());
        RequestBody phone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etPhone.getText().toString());
        RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etEmail.getText().toString());
        RequestBody password = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etPass.getText().toString());
        RequestBody username = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), etUsername.getText().toString());

        SignUpApi getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(SignUpApi.class);
        Call<SignUpResponseModel> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename, name, phone, email, password, username);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Response<SignUpResponseModel> response) {

                SignUpResponseModel signUpResponseModel = (SignUpResponseModel) response.body();
                if (signUpResponseModel != null) {
                    if (signUpResponseModel.getStatus() == 1) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        ToastMessage.showToast(context, signUpResponseModel.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        btnSend.setText(signUpResponseModel.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    assert signUpResponseModel != null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

SignUpResponseModel:

```
public class SignUpResponseModel {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private int status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

response on PostMan:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j058w.jpg)

Comment: post your API end point.

Comment: share your post request also.

Comment: post updated sir.

Comment: sorry, I add it. @JakirHossain

Comment: when I see onResponse not worked, add onFailure. I see this error in Throwable.

Comment: @JakirHossain Add it.

Comment: @JakirHossain add method completely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the wrong `JSON response` when you call your API from the device. It can be an issue in your server. Let's say when you call your API using postman then you are getting your expected response like below(because your API call is ok)

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Successful"
}
```

And when you call you API from your application then you get the wrong `JSON response` from the server means API call is not ok [it can be happned due to many reasons].

```
"{
"status": 0,
"message": ""
}"
```

So you will get an exception that you are expecting an object in response but you're getting a string.

You can get the response from API and convert it to string using `ResponseBody` from `okhttp`  like this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = getResponse.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename, name, phone, email, password, username);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
             try {
                // here you can what response you are getting.
                Log.d("JSON From Server", response.body().string());//convert reponse to string
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
      }
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
          Log.i("error", t.getMessage());
      }
  });
```

And also use `ResponseBody` in your API endpoint like below

```
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile.....
```

Comment: what is "ResponseBody"? I have to make 'uploadFile' return 'okhttp3.ResponseBody' ?

Comment: ResponseBody is OkHttp3 class.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting status and message response show the variable that is set in the url may be that is conflicting.I means

```
@Part("sample_disc") RequestBody imageFile,
                                     @Part("name") RequestBody name,// May be these variable name are not exact 
                                     @Part("phone") RequestBody phone,
                                     @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                                     @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                                     @Part("username") RequestBody username);
```

Comment: these variables are to send information to the server. its wrong?

Comment: that's why saying check these variable

Comment: these kind or error occurs when your variable not matching with the server variable

Comment: if Submitted variables are not matching with the server variables, No problem. in response, the message shows me that error.

Answer (score 0):

{
"status": 1,
"
message": "Successful"
}
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

clearly says that in your response value of the message is a string type but expected is a JSON object.
so instead of "successful" it could be an JSON Object.

Comment: in web service, return the response like this: echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "Successful"));   it is not a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

In your response you are getting the response as a string but its require json object 
for example

```
"{
 "status": 1,
 "message": "Successful"
 }" -- you are getting this 

 but you required -  {
 "status": 1,
 "message": "Successful"
 }
```

Comment: in web service, return the response like this: echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "Successful")); it is not a JSON?